# Execution Time Out (12000 ms) for the task "Sum of intervals" Codewars

Tags: c, algorithm, sum, intervals

The site codewars.com has a task "Sum of intervals".
https://www.codewars.com/kata/52b7ed099cdc285c300001cd

The bottom line is to find the sum of the intervals, taking into account the overlap.
For example:

```
sum_intervals((const struct interval[]){
   {1,4},
   {7, 10},
   {3, 5}
}, 3); /* => 7 */
```

The sum of the numbers on the intervals {1,4}, {7,10}, {3,5} is equal to 7. It should be taken into account that the intervals {1,4} and {3,5} overlap.
I'm doing this task in C:

```
struct interval {
    int first;
    int second;
};
int sum_intervals(const struct interval* intervals, const size_t ints_size)
{
    int seq_size = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ints_size; i++)
        seq_size += intervals[i].second - intervals[i].first;

    int* sequence = malloc(seq_size * sizeof(int));
    int iter = 0;
    
    for (unsigned int i= 0; i < ints_size; i++) {
        int k = intervals[i].second;
        for (int j = intervals[i].first; j < k; j++) {
            sequence[iter] = j;
            iter++;
        }
    }
    int unq_seq_size = seq_size;
    qsort(sequence, seq_size, sizeof(int), compare);

    for (int i = 0; i < seq_size - 1; i++)
    if (sequence[i] == sequence[i + 1]) unq_seq_size--;
    
    free(sequence);
    return unq_seq_size;
}
int compare(const void* x1, const void* x2) {
    return (*(int*)x1 - *(int*)x2); 
}
```

First, I determine what size array is needed to store all the numbers in the intervals by calculating `int seq_size`. Then I allocate memory for the `int*sequency` array, after which I fill it with numbers between the boundaries of each of the intervals. Next, I sort the array, after which, to find the sum, it will be sufficient to compare neighboring elements for equality and, in case of equality, reduce the sum `int unq_seq_size`.

The code satisfies the tests, but is further considered a failure because "Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)". Help me optimize the code, or suggest another approach?

I calculated the execution time of the function using the following construct:

```
float startTime = (float) clock()/CLOCK_PER_SEC;
/* Do work */
float endTime = (float) clock()/CLOCK_PER_SEC;
float timeElapsed = endTime - startTime;
```

As a result, `int timeElapsed` is equal to 0.004000. Next, I applied this construction to individual blocks and got that all this time is spent on sorting:

```
float startTime = (float)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
qsort(sequence, seq_size, sizeof(int), compare);
float endTime = (float)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
float timeElapsed = endTime - startTime;
printf("%f",timeElapsed ); //0.004000
```

Also, at the end of the assignment there is a similar text:
"Random tests"
Up to 32 intervals from the range [-10^9, 10^9].
Can these 0.004000 at the interval [-10^9, 10^9] give "Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)"?

Comment: If it's correct but not fast enough, optimizing it is the right approach, yes. What have you tried? Where is most time spent? Note that without metrics (and not just the online judge's opinion) you can't reasonably optimize code. Can you provide a [mcve] for others to look at, of course including the according input data?

Comment: Your algorithm looks fairly complicated and the inner `for` loop and `qsort` may have to deal with big intervals or a big array. My proposed algorithm: 1. sort the intervals by their first value in ascending order, 2. check adjacent intervals for overlap and combine overlapping intervals, 3. sum up the lengths of the remaining (non-overlapping) intervals.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I've added a link to the task and the executing time.

Comment: I see no link. In any case, do prepare a [mcve], which includes a `main()` function. External links that contain fundamental context info are not really good. Aim at a single, self-contained and concise question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solution is too slow effectively, as it is related to the range of data, which may be huge.

If `n` is the number of intervals, here is a `O(n logn)` solution.

1. Sort the intervals according to the start of them, and if equal to the end of them
2. Perform an iterative linear examination of the intervals as follows:

   - sum = 0
   - current_start = interval[0].first
   - current_end = interval[0].second
   - Do i = 1 to n-1

     - if (interval[i].first > current_end) then

       - sum += current_end - current_start
       - current_start = interval[i].first
       - current_end = interval[i].second
     - else

       - current_end = max (current_end, interval[i].second)
   - sum += current_end - current_start

Comment: For `{1,5},{8,11}, {2,7}` sum is `6`, why?

Comment: Check my answer please.

Answer (score 0):

For Damien'c answer:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct interval {
    int first;
    int second;
}interval;

int compare(const void* x1, const void* x2);
int sum_intervals(struct interval* intervals, size_t ints_size);
int main()
{
    printf("sum: %d", sum_intervals((struct interval[])
    {
        {1,5},{8,11}, {2,7}
        }, 3));
    return 0;
}

int compare(const void* x1, const void* x2) {
    return ((interval*)x1)->first - ((interval*)x2)->first;
}

int sum_intervals(struct interval* intervals, size_t ints_size) {
    qsort(intervals,ints_size, sizeof(interval),compare);
    for (int i = 0; i < ints_size; i++) {
        printf("%d", intervals[i].first);
        printf("  %d\n", intervals[i].second);
    }
    int current_first = intervals[0].first;
    int current_second = intervals[0].second;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < ints_size-1; i++) {
        if (current_second < intervals[i].first) {
            sum += current_second - current_first;
            current_first = intervals[i].first;
            current_second = intervals[i].second;
        } else current_second = max(current_second, intervals[i].second);
    }
    sum += current_second - current_first;
   
    return sum;
}
```

Am I wrong somewhere? Because the answer is 6.

```
1  5
2  7
8  11
sum: 6
```

Comment: @Damien Corrected, on test 4 out of 5 this is what happened
*Actual*: 1
*Expected*: 3
*Intervals*:
   [
     [2147483588, 2147483589],
     [-125, -123]
   ]

Comment: @Damien My comparator looks like:
`int compare(const void* x1, const void* x2) {
    if (((interval*)x1)->first == ((interval*)x2)->first)
        return ((interval*)x1)->second - ((interval*)x2)->second;
    return ((interval*)x1)->first - ((interval*)x2)->first;
}`
But it's still the same

Comment: Here is my comp:
`int compare(const void* x1, const void* x2) {
    const interval* px1 = x1;
    const interval* px2 = x2;
    return (px1->first > px2->first) - (px1->first < px2->first);
}`

Task is done. Thank you